# Error running RNetCDF library in R

Tags: r, netcdf

I'm having difficulty installing this R package.  It seems to install, but then fails to run with the following error.  The `type='source'` also fails.  Any idea what's going wrong?

```
> install.packages('RNetCDF')
Installing package into ‘/Users/robinedwards/Library/R/3.1/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.1/RNetCDF_1.6.2-3.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2112407 bytes (2.0 Mb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 2.0 Mb


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/_s/ppznw4sx7p51kwv__hj3d8540000gn/T//RtmptxKC3g/downloaded_packages
> require(RNetCDF)
Loading required package: RNetCDF
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'RNetCDF', details:
  call: NULL
  error: I/O error (udunits)
```

Comment: I was able to install it fine on Ubuntu 14.04 with R 3.1.0. Do you have udunits and netcdf installed on your computer?

Comment: Works for me too in Windows with R 3.1.1, we need more information about your computer, IDE, R version, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be udunits2, which RNetCDF uses and ncdf does not.  Specifically

```
>> --with-udunits-lib='/soft/local/udunits-2.1.23/lib'"
```

is that path in the ld.so cache or in LD_LIBRARY_PATH?  If not, it will not be found by dlload.

I actually found several threads about this error and every one of them involved Mac OS X. Is that what you're running?

Source: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-September/289074.html

Comment: Ah that's it. Funny I don't recall installing it for my previous OSX setup with RNetCDF, which worked fine. But after `brew install udunits` the package runs no problem. Cheers